# Using Nightwatchjs To Detect Video Play

Tags: javascript, video, nightwatch.js

I'm testing an app that includes a video player. I'd like Nightwatch to identify that the video is playing after it hits the play button and pauses when it hits the pause button. I'm not talking about detecting a play or pause event that the player sends but detecting if the video is actually playing. Any ideas how to detect if the video is indeed playing or paused?

Answer (score 1):

Here can be the answare you are looking for: https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html
with video.paused event you can see if the video is paused or not..

Comment: to add to this, you may need to run browser side javascript to detect this via the execute function http://nightwatchjs.org/api#execute